# OAuth ForceServiceConnector allows access to same connection for any Salesforce User

Tags: java, database, sdk, salesforce

I am developing a Spring Java salesforce app and using Database SDK 22.0.8-BETA and OAuth 2.0 to authenticated user login. Basically use Salesforce as identity provider and get connection to work with data in Salesforce. I hit what seem to be OAuth SDK problem.

My case is following:

For the 1st user it works perfectly well he gets OAuth token, redirect to app page and connection to the org all works great!
Now the PROBLEM! Get 2nd browser session and try login to the same app with different User on different ORG, the OAuth works again and let 2nd user into the app BUT this user now also has same connection as user #1 so they share same connection given by SDK even though they are from totally different ORG. I must be missing something simple in Spring or Security config to make 2 users connect to their different orgs and get separate connections. I try many different settings nothing seem to work, ForceServiceConnector always returns the connection for the 1st initial authenticated user to all incoming sessions regardless where they come from or what browser it is or what user it is. So anyone with Salesforce USER ID always get the same #1 user connection instead of their own ORG connection based on their user authentication.

Anyone knows this problem or how to configure Spring Security with this SDK to allow user to get their separate connection via OAuth?

I use this code in Controller to get User information:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Inject
    ForceServiceConnector oauth_app_connector;

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException, ConnectionException {
    uid = oauth_app_connector.getConnection().getUserInfo().getUserName();
```

...........

Hope somebody is doing this or have solved this can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The ForceServiceConnector is only for reading in the configured connection. So you'll get whatever username you configured in your connection URL every time.

Instead of using that use the ForceSecurityContext to get the user logged in by OAuth:

```
SecurityContext sc = ForceSecurityContextHolder.get(false);
```

More info:
http://forcedotcom.github.com/java-sdk/retrieve-user-data

You can find a full example that uses this to hit the Chatter API as the logged in user here:
https://github.com/jsimone/chatterToDo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/force/sample/service/ChatterService.java